# Mostrar un mensaje cada 5 iteraciones en Java

Tags: java, bucle-for, bucles

Buen día, estoy tratando de hacer un código en Java, en el que el usuario ingresa el número de veces que se va a imprimir un resultado, en mi caso es "el número de kilómetros que recorre un caballo", y con base en el número que ingrese el usuario, cada 5 kilómetros imprimir que el caballo se encontró un objeto en el camino (dicho objeto, el cual el usuario escoge, afectará la salud del caballo o del usuario). En fin, el problema que estoy teniendo es que no puedo hacer que cada 5 kilómetros le aparezca el mensaje al usuario. (Espero haberme dado a entender) El intento de código que llevo es lo siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.logging.Level;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class reto {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int a;
    String b, c;
    System.out.println("¿Cual es el nombre de tu caballo?");
    b=sc.next();
    System.out.println("¿Cuantos kilometros quieres que avance "+b+"?");
    a=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++)
    {
        try {
            System.out.println(b+" recorrio 1 kilometro");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Reto12.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    if(a%5==0)
    {
        System.out.println("¿Que hay frente al caballo?(pasto/trampa/bomba/vida)");
        c=sc.next();
    }

}

}
```

¡Gracias de antemano!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay dos problemas en tu código: el primero es que la comparación debe ir dentro del bucle; el segundo es que debes usar `i` para comparar, ya que es `i` quien cuenta los kilómetros recorridos.

Así debería funcionar:

```
for(int i=1;i<=a;i++)
{
    try {
        System.out.println(b+" recorrio 1 kilometro");
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        if(i%5==0)
        {
            System.out.println("¿Que hay frente al caballo?(pasto/trampa/bomba/vida)");
            c=sc.next();
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reto12.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```